# What is the purpose of gitlab-runner

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use gitlab ci/cd to test and deploy my application. The setup tutorial guide me install and use gitlab runner. I followed the guideline, install runner on my VPS and run pipeline job successfully but **my app didn't run on my VPS**.

I found the documentation say that gitlab runner **run your jobs and send the results back to GitLab** So what is gitlab runner used for? And how to automatically deploy my application on VPS.

Thank you!

Comment: Your jobs are the building, testing and deploying of the application. Those are done using the runners (gitlab doesn't run your build commands locally, but on the runners). You can configure a gitlab stage with your deployment commands (e.g. ssh onto your machine and do something). 
You could use the VPS for both the runners and your application, though for production you usually wouldn't.

Comment: So gitlab-runner just use to run test and build phase, and I must write another code to deploy my app.

Comment: You can use the gitlab runner to deploy (as in, run the deployment scripts/mechanisms), but not as a deployment target. So yes, you'll need to write something to deploy your application into your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You have your project along with a .gitlab-ci.yml file. .gitlab-ci.yml defines what stages your CI/CD pipeline has and what to do in each stage. This typically consists of a build,test,deploy stages. Within each stage you can define multiple job. For example in build stage you may have 3 jobs to build on debian, centos and windows (in GitLab glossary build:debian, build:centos, build:windows). A GitLab runner clones the project read the gitlab-ci.yaml file and do what he is instructed to do. So basically GitLab runner is a Golang process that executes some instructed tasks.